# Какой apk файл весит больше? Unity

Tags: unity3d

Что весит больше в Unity? 1 сцена с 10ью разными фотографиями или 10 сцен, на каждой из которых по 1ой фотографии? В чём суть вопроса: влияет ли как-то количество сцен на размер apk файла? Спасибо.

Comment: Сделайте оба варианта да посмотрите размер?

Comment: Ну подумайте, где будет больше 1 сцена и 10 фоток или 10 сцен и 10 фоток. Другое дело, как эти 10 фоток упаковать на сцене...

Comment: Сама сцена, по сути, текстовый файл. Он весит очень мало. Но содержимое сцены может занимать много дискового пространства. Поэтому не стоит озадачиваться кол-вом сцен. Нужно работать с содержимым - уменьшать размер, оптимизировать модели и пр. И не стоит бездумно кидать в папки и подпапки "Resources" всякий контент, особенно, который не используется, т.к. всё это попадает в билд.

Comment: Спасибо всем. Я всё понял.

Answer (score 0):

Будет весит больше вариант с 10 сценами. Так как вы всеравно храните ресурсы(ваши изображения) и так юнити хранит одну сцену, в которой десять объектов, сам соранённый объект весит очень мало. А если делать через вариант с 10 сценами надо хранить все данные об этих сценах хоть они и будут практически идентичными.

Так же через компонент SpriteRenderer можно менять спрайт одного объекта. Тоесть 1 сцена с одним объектом.